# sample datatable bind to gridview not working in vs2019- 2017

Tags: vb.net

create DataTable and bind to GridView in ASP.Net
NOR working in vs2019

Hello all,
My goal is to present some generated data in a Gridview.
One can achieve this by first creating a datatable and then bind it with a Grid view.
I found several examples on the internet and tested them with vs2017 and vs2019.
No single example worked, not even the simplest example shown below.
Why those code behind errors?
How can I solve this ?
Hopefully someone knows a solution.

I did download the sample from:
https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Dynamically-create-DataTable-and-bind-to-GridView-in-ASPNet.aspx

```
   HTML:=======================================

 <form id="form1"runat="server">

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-    ForeColor="White"
runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ItemStyle-Width="30"/>
<asp:BoundField D ataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-       Width="150"/>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" ItemStyle-Width ="150"/>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
</form>

    Co de behind =======================================
OptionExplici tOn
OptionStrict Off

Imports System.Data

Public Class WebForm2
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender AsObject, e AsEventArgs) HandlesMe.Load
Dim dt As New DataTable()


dt.Columns.AddRange(New DataColumn() {New DataColumn("Id", GetType  (Integer)), New DataColumn("Name", GetType(String)), New DataColumn   ("Country", GetType(String))})

dt.Rows.Add(1, "John Hammond", "United States")
dt.Rows.Add(2, "Mudassar Khan", "India")
dt.Rows.Add(3, "Suzanne Mathews", "France")
dt.Rows.Add(4, "Robert Schidner", "Russia")

GridView1.DataSource = dt
GridView1.DataBind()
EndSub


EndClass
```

ERRPRS =======================================

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error BC30451 'GridView1' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due
>   to its protection level.  Algemeen test  chart    S:\P2 S VSlab\Algemeen
>   test  chart\Algemeen test  chart\Gridtest 1.aspx.vb   18  Active
>   Error BC30451 'GridView1' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due
>   to its protection level.  Algemeentest  chart S:\P2 S VSlab\Algemeen
>   test  chart\Algemeen test  chart\Gridtest 1.aspx.vb   19  Active

I did download the sample from:
https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Dynamically-create-DataTable-and-bind-to-GridView-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: "OptionStrict Off" Oh No! Option Strict should almost always On.

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work. However you do have this:

ForeColor="White"

So, that sets the text of the data to white, and your web page is white, so you not see the data. I would just remove the above.

## Edit

The HTML page (this is asp.net + web forms, right????) is this:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebGridTest.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" Width="75px" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <br />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the VB code is:

```
Public Class WebForm1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        If Me.IsPostBack = False Then

            Dim dt As New DataTable()

            dt.Columns.AddRange({New DataColumn("Id", GetType(Integer)),
                                New DataColumn("Name", GetType(String)),
                                New DataColumn("Country", GetType(String))})

            dt.Rows.Add(1, "John Hammond", "United States")
            dt.Rows.Add(2, "Mudassar Khan", "India")
            dt.Rows.Add(3, "Suzanne Mathews", "France")
            dt.Rows.Add(4, "Robert Schidner", "Russia")

            GridView1.DataSource = dt
            GridView1.DataBind()

        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: `HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"` works fine. It sets the column headers' background to a pleasant blue with white text.

Comment: Ok. The code + markup as above works just fine.  So perhaps something like the form ID is wrong.  I would add a new web form page (web form page, not HTML page, nor a MVC page). Remember, your example code as posted is a asp.net page, not mvc page, nor is it a html page. So, for this to work as posted, try adding a new "web form", and try again.  Let VS generate the base markup for that page, and only cut + paste in ONLY the gridview part you have - and paste inside of the form tags. You also note that your example does not work - any error messages appearing should also be noted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved.
I always tested this example in a test project that I always use to try new tools.
I have now tried the example in another project and now it works!
I have no idea why, maybe it has something to do with "tableadapror" because that is the only difference between these projects.
Very misteriues.
Thank you so much for the answers and sorry for bothering you.
Kind regards from amazing Thailand.